# I don't connecton with my Azure SQL from ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I'm new in azure cloud, so I have asp.net application. I want add ado.NET item. I try with connection string. Add connection there not run I add new connection there not run.
I don't  understand. How add my entity framework classes to azure?

- A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
  was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
  SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
  Network Interfaces, error: 40 - Error Could not open a connection a SQL Server ).

I new in asp.net too, so How I work with azure and asp.net?

Comment: If you log into your Azure dashboard, select your Azure database and on the bottom-right "Quick Glance", there is an option for "Show connection strings". You will find an entry for ADO.NET there. Copy and paste it into your code/config file and don't forget to replace `Password={your_password_here}` with your real password.

Comment: <connectionStrings>
      <add name="MyDB"
          connectionString="Server=tcp:server.database.windows.net,1433;Database=mysSweetDB;User ID=login@server;Password=*******;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30"  And I and my ip on site, and off firewall.
          xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    </connectionStrings>  This is my connection string. I add in web.confing, and web.config relase.

Comment: And I add ip on site, and off firewall.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure a firewall rule to enable you to connect to the database. You can do this from the portal.

[How to configure firewall for database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj553530.aspx)

Comment: I configured firewall on azure website.

Comment: have you created a database?